# Is it possible to add a template to a widget using $this->getchild?

Tags: template, widgets, new-products

I'd like to add some pagination for a widget that i'm adding to a CMS page.  Is it possible to add a template to this widgets .phtml page or is there any other way for me implement this functionality?

The template is located at:

> app/design/frontend/namespace/default/template/catalog/layer/view.phtml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add children blocks to a widget one approach would be to simply create the block directly from the layout.

```
$this->getLayout()->createBlock('what_block/you_need')->setTemplate('the/blocks/template.phtml')->toHtml();
```

You could incorporate this into a function inside the widget's block file like `getMyBlockHtml` and then in the widget's template simply call `echo $this->getMyBlockHtml()`

Comment: How would I call the above template?

Comment: @easymoden00b exactly the same way should work. You should be able to call `$this->getLayout()` from any template.

Comment: Got it to work a relatively short amount of time afterwards, thanks.